# do a postback with javascript to a certain Page Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

What I'm doing now is this:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<asp:Button runat='server' OnClick='OnDoClick' ID="b1" />
<asp:HiddenField runat='server' ID="SecretValue" />
</div>

function doPostb(value)
{
   $('#SecretValue').val(value);
   $('#<%=b1.ClientID%>').click();
}
```

so basically I need to post to a page method and send some value to it

anybody knows a more straightforward way of doing this ?

Comment: I can't get that why you mentioned about PageMethods ??

Comment: @Sreekumar OnDoClick is a Page method

Comment: if u want page to be reloaded wht u want to give a PageMethod in a button click ? ... use direct method.. pagemethods are used for getting data with our reloading...

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward? Wrap your div in a form tag and do:

```
$("#your_new_form").submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without the page re-loading, you could try [jQuery's post function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

If you want to do it without the page re-loading, you could try [jQuery's submit function](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), which would behave the same as the click of a submit button, but might be more semantically appropriate.

You might also want to look at [asp.net's doPostBack function](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function).

Comment: I want to do a postback, which involves page reloading

Comment: postbacks do not necessarily involve full page reloads. You could post via AJAX and alter your content using JavaScript. I've updated my answer with a non-AJAX approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__doPostBack` method of asp.net Client-library.

```
function doPostb(value)
{
   $('#SecretValue').val(value);
   __doPostBack('<%=b1.UniqueD%>','');
}
```

I can't get that why you mentioned about PageMethods ??

Comment: you can see there my button 'b1' has a OnClick='OnDoClick', OnDoClick is a Page Method which will be called on b1 Click, which is why I do $('#<%=b1.ClientID%>').click();